# Sympy: Is there a function that gives all the factors of an expression but does not work sums?

Tags: sympy

I have an expression which is composed only of factors (e.g. `(x**2+1)*(x**2)*(x+4)`. I want to delete the factor `x**2` from it using the function .args with an if condition. However, if I have the following equation `x**2+1+x+4`, the .args thinks I have `x**2` in the expression which is not true (I only have one factor). I have the code below.:

```
if q**2 in expr.args:        
   expr = expr.func(*[term for term in expr.args if term != q**2])
else:
   expr = expr*2
```

Comment: You could ask the expression for its type before making a decision: `if expr.is_Mul and q**2 in expr.args: expr/=q**2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Mul.make_args(expr)` you will get a singleton if the expression is not a product, otherwise a tuple of the factors:

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> from sympy import Mul
>>> Mul.make_args(x + y)
(x + y,)
>>> Mul.make_args(x*y)
(x, y)
```